# cl Compiler throws errors for external header file

Tags: c, hardware

I am working on a project where I need to control some hardware through an API provided by the manufacturer of the device. There are code-examples given, which should compile fine. Some of the functionality is defined in .h-header files provided with the API. When I copy and paste one of the programming examples into my .c-file (including the referenced .h-Headers in the same folder) the `cl` compiler I access through my VS 2017 Native Tools Command Prompt throws excpetions/errors, mostly C2059 and C2061 errors. For example:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25019 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

pco_controller.c
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(155): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'SHORT'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(156): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'ZZwAlignDummy'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(156): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(157): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'dwStatusDll'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(157): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(158): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'dwStatusDrv'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(158): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
c:\users\optical microscope\desktop\vinzenz\pco.edge 5.5\pco_controller\sc2_SDKS
tructures.h(159): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

When we take a look into the `sc2_SDKStructures.h` file, we find:

```
typedef struct                         // Buffer list structure for  PCO_WaitforBuffer
{
 SHORT sBufNr;
 WORD  ZZwAlignDummy;
 DWORD dwStatusDll;
 DWORD dwStatusDrv;                    // 12
} PCO_Buflist;
```

As I am totally new to C-programming I dont understand the errors and given the fact that the headers were provided by the manufacturer of the hardware, I dont see why their code should be wrong.

Comment: SHORT is defined in yet another header file. find that one and include it in sdkstructures.h. it's probably windows.h

Comment: The same holds true, of course, for WORD and DWORD, which are probably declared in the same file.

Comment: Can I also include it in my actual source code or do I need to include them in every Header file (as I use some of them and there are multiple errors for every included header file)